# How to present large dataset from a SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, dataset

I have a query, which in essence returns several million rows. There is about 10 columns of varying length.

(A report that returns all sales orders, lines, costs, customer etc. for the past 10 years)

Normally, most of my queries are done through SQL Server Reporting Services and grouped using SQL Server Reporting grouping. They only have ever been done for 1-3 months as that's all the relevance required.

This resultset is significantly larger and can not be run - in SSRS, it stays on 'loading' for approximately 15 minutes before the site times out or the db servers cpu usage stays at a constant 100% utilisation. No resultset is produced.

I have come up with a work around solution which uses MSAccess to link to the SQL Server view that I have created.

Is there something simple that can be done in SSRS or Visual Studio/BIDS that could attack this or should I look toward a 'big data' solution?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What do you intend to do with all of this data?  Are you aggregating it at all or is it detail data?

Comment: Are you able to run this query in SSMS and generate a return?